# Dexie: How to get only one column in the result by column key? (simple array of values insted of objects)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, dexie

I have this fetch query

```js
await useDatabase.data.where("ts").between(ms - 1000, ms).toArray();
```

I get the result properly but as an object of data.

```
[
    {
        "ts": 60.1875,
        "sample": 0,
        "id": 1
    }, 
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
]
```

is it possible to minimise the size of the result by choosing a single column instead of getting a whole object result of a row?
(for sample)

```
[0,...]
```

didn't find anything in docs. maybe i'm missing it or using the wrong search keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you have a compound index of the queried column along with the other column you'd like to return.

```
const useDatabase = new Dexie('myDatabase');
useDatabase.version(2).stores({
  data: 'id, [ts+sample]'
]);

await useDatabase.data.where("[ts+sample]").between(
  [ms - 1000, Dexie.minKey],
  [ms, Dexie.maxKey]
).keys();
```

This will give an array of [ms, sample] tuples only.

```json
[
    [60.1875, 0], 
    ...
]
```

You could map it to only get the 'sample' prop:

```
result.map(([ts, sample]) => sample)
```

But if performance is of no concert, you could always do this from the original request (without adding the index):

```
result.map(({sample}) => sample)
```

Comment: I made the change on my tables `++id, [ts+sample]`. the db structure looks cool now. then i trigger an async function with an await for my db request `const f = async()=>{ await db.channel0.where...` and i get undefined in the result (`console.log(f())`)

Comment: btw you definitly read my mind, im trying to display a (apex) chart of data samples ts:sample

Comment: ooh i missed the between thing. accepts 2 different arrays for each, ts and sample? what is exactly happening there?

Comment: When utilizing the composite index [ts+sample], the 'between' clause must give a composite lower- and upper key. Every entry in the index consists of an array [timestamp, sample], so to search, both the lower- and upper bounds need to be of that format. In this case, we're only interested of the timestamp, so we don't care about sample values, that's why we give that part a generic value (Dexie.minKey and Dexie.maxKey). If you wouldn't want to include timestamps equal to upper bound, use Dexie.minKey on both places.